# Where does a Basic Card go on users phone after they exit Assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm testing an AoG in development and sent a Basic Card to my phone. I later went to find/retrieve the card, and can't find it anywhere.

Searched in the Assistant, in Activity, and could find the invocation and information about it, including details, but couldn't find the Basic Card that was delivered to my screen earlier in the day.

I'm doing this in Dialogflow, so presume the code is ok, as it's delivering the Basic Card ok.

I'm wondering why the card I received isn't available, or at least available anywhere within an obvious search.

Comment: As far as I understand, basic cards aren't intended to be locally persistent outside the lifecycle of a Google Assistant conversation. Sending an email or text message might be better options, if you anticipate your user referring back to the info your action provided.

Comment: Thanks, Max. Email or text aren't really an option given my scenario, unfortunately.